# FloatingActionButton no border?

Tags: android, material-design

I cannot find a way to get a FAB with no border. For example when I try:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android.support.design:fabSize="normal"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    style="@style/Fab"/>
```

I get:

[image: Screenshot]

Notice the border still around the FAB. I have tried adjustViewBounds="true" and android:background="@android:color/transparent" both of which are the suggested solutions for getting rid of the border on an ImageView (which FAB extends) but neither work. How can I get rid of this border?

Note: all @style/Fab does is position the button, nothing to do with border.

Comment: Also tried android:scaleType="fitXY", same result

Comment: Why are you trying to build a transparent FAB?

Comment: Try setting borderwidth as 0dp..app:borderWidth="0dp"

Comment: Implementing a shadow for it. Transparency is just an example, just really need to get rid of the border.

Comment: Also, I've noticed the blue border is coming from AppTheme.

Comment: @KevCron I just added the same in as an answer. You can accept it if it helped you :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just add `app:borderWidth="0dp"` in your layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android.support.design:fabSize="normal"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    style="@style/Fab"/>
```

There is also added advantage of adding this, it fixes the problem of square FAB in API<15.

Update: The latest update for android support does not need borderwidth=0dp to fix the square FAB.

Comment: I tried getting rid of the background of my FAB and it did not work. No effect at all for the line 'android:background="@android:color/transparent"'.

Comment: I even tried changing the color of that line but my FAB comes all the time with the same color which is taken from color file 'colorPrimary'. When I changed that color the FAB background color changes.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to comment by @Zvi

To make background of the button transparent, use this line :

```
app:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
```

The hash code for transparent background is : `#00FFFFFF`

To change the color of the icon inside the button, use this :

```
android:tint="#800080"
```

`#800080` is the hash code for purple

For accessing hash codes for different colors, go here: http://www.color-hex.com/color-palettes/

Just copy the hash codes and paste it wherever you want it.

Comment: Do you mean by setting the button background color to transparent will remove the border? Otherwise, I do not see how this answers the question.

Comment: This was the answer to comment by @Zvi

Comment: Yeah, but he should ask his own question then.

Comment: To change the color of the icon inside the button, use this :
 app:tint="@android:color/white"

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

How stupid of me. Thank you @Ranjith.

This somehow also added a shadow under the button:

[image]

Comment: your icon is the wrong size, though. The icon should be 24dp. see https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/content/drawable-hdpi/ic_send_white_24dp.png (also available the xhdpi, xxhdpi... versions) and oddly centered

Comment: I know, this app is just for testing. Thank you though.